# Current tab url in Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox

I did search and tried several options - does not work. Please help ;)

I'm trying to add a button in Firefox that would do onclick:

1. copy currently opened website url ex. http://example.com
2. open in new tab my script + above url as parameter, ex. http://ExampleMySite.com/script.php?url=http://example.com

Here's my addon code:

```js
function useThisLink() {

    browser.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true}).then(function(tabs){
        var currentTabUrl = tabs[0].url;
    });

    var toMyURL = 'http://MySiteAddress.com/script.php?url='+currentTabUrl;

    browser.tabs.create({
        "url": toMyURL
    });
}

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(useThisLink);
```

Comment: What's the problem with this code? What is currently not working? Please try to be more specific than *does not work* :D

Comment: Problem solved!!!!

Comment: 1. I needed TABS permissions in the manifest
2. final code is as simple as this:

function useThisLink() {
 browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  tabUrl = tabs[0].url;
 });
 browser.tabs.create({
  "url": 'here-is-my-parser-address.php&link='+tabUrl+''
 });
}
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(useThisLink);